# How can I fetch a data while calculating it at first?

Tags: php

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT Country, Quantity FROM `table 1`");

$rows = array();
while($r = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
$row[0] = $r[0];
$row[1] = $r[1];
array_push($rows,$row);
}

print json_encode($rows, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
```

How can I fetch a data while calculating it at first? I need to add below code to the above code and display in graph.

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result1)){
            echo "Total Quantity = ". $row['SUM(quantity)'];
            echo "<br />";
```

Comment: you can make all your calculations inside your while loop

Comment: `$result` and `$result1` belong to the same or different queries? If the later, how to match the results?

Comment: please stop using `mysql_*`. use `mysqli_*` OR `PDO`

Comment: *and display in a graph*: that is a whole other matter than the question title mentions. What have you attempted in order to produce your graph?

Comment: I don't get what the OP is trying to do. Why not just `echo` what you need within the first `while` loop?

Answer (score 1):

You can simply get your total by `SUM in mysql`

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT SUM(column_name) AS TotalFROM `table 1`");
```

or you can sum it in your `while loop`

```
    $total = '';    
    $rows = array();
    while($r = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $row[0] = $r[0];
    $row[1] = $r[1];
    $total = $r[1] + $total;
    array_push($rows,$row);
    }
    $rows[]['total'] = $total;
    echo "<pre>";print_r($rows );
```

**Also use `PDO` or `mysqli` prepared statements `mysql` is `depreciated` and completely removed in `PHP7`**

Answer (score 0):

You can add a total row by keeping a running total in your loop, and after the loop you can add that total to the array:

```
$total = 0;
while($r = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $total += $r[1];
    $rows[] = $r;
}
$rows[] = ['Total', $total];
```

Note that:

- you don't need to copy each value one by one (like `$row[0] = $r[0];`), you can just assign the whole array;
- adding to an array can be done with `array_push`, but `$rows[] =` also works, and probably faster.
- `mysql_` functions have been deprecated for a long time now, and are no longer supported in the current version of PHP (7.x). Please [use `mysqli_` functions or `PDO` instead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php).